# positive operator and second moment

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, operator-theory, moment-map

Let $\mathcal{SM}_n^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of symmetric positive semidefinite $n\times n-$ real matrices. Denote $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Borel-sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$. A map 
$$F:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\longrightarrow \mathcal{SM}_n^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
such that:

(i) $F(\mathbb{R}^n)=I_n$

(ii) If $(A_i)$ is a countable family of pairwise disjoint Borel sets, then
$$F(\cup_iA_i)=\sum_iF(A_i)$$

my question is under which conditions there is a probability measure $\mu$ related to $F$ through 
$$\forall \ \ A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\ \ F(A)=\int_A xx^Td\mu(x)\ \ \ (*)$$

help plz thx

Answer (score 1):

Revised, 29 Sept 2017. From your data you can find a finite  measure $\nu$ and a function $\phi: \mathbb R^n\to\mathcal{SM}_n^+(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $F(A)=\int_A \phi(x)d\nu(x)$, as shown in the next paragraph. If your $(*)$ holds, $d\mu = 1/\|x\|^2 d\nu$. The condition you seek is  that $\phi(x)=xx^T/\|x\|^2$ for $\nu$-almost all $x$; only this way will $(*)$ be verified.  One necessary condition is that if $A=\{x: \|x\|\le t\}$ then $\operatorname{tr}(A)\le t^2$. Others, too complicated to state here, put constraints on $F(A)$ when  $A=B(x,r),$ the $r$-ball centered at $x$: then  $F(A)$ must be in the cone of psd matrices generated by some neighborhood of $xx^T$.

Here is the recipe for $\nu$ and $\phi$: Let $\nu(A) = \operatorname{tr}(F(A))$.  Observe that the matrix elements of $F$ define signed measures: $m_{ij}(A) = F(A)_{ij}$.  It is easy to check that each $m_{ij}\ll\nu$, so the Radon Nikodym derivatives $\phi_{ij}(x) = \frac{dm_{ij}}{d\nu}$ exist, with the stated property that $F(A)=\int_A \phi(x)d\nu(x)$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but $\phi_{ij} ≠(xx^t)_{ij}$ i don't get why you define the measure $\nu(A)=tr(F(A))/n$ you can explain it to me thanks

Comment: The division by $n$ is to make it a probability measure.  The use of trace is to make $\nu$ dominate your $F$.  If $A$ is such that $\nu(A)=0$ then we know $F(A)=0$ because that's how psd matrices work.  I don't understand your comment that $\phi_{ij}\ne(xx^t)_{ij}$.  If your $F$ is constructed from a $\mu$ as you want , then $\phi_{ij}$ *will* equal $(xx^t)_{ij}$.  But most $F$ satisfying your (i) and (ii) do not come from a $\mu$ as in your ( * ), and for them, yes $\phi(x)\ne xx^t$.  I construct $\nu$ from $F$ and derive a checkable condition for your (*) to be true.

Comment: my question is : if i have an operator F which verifies (i) and (ii) and Im looking for other ''conditions'' (i knew that i and ii are not  enough) to have a measure $\mu$ related to  F through (*)

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers i have resolved the problem thanks so much